# remove <![CDATA[ tag from xml webserivce responses

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I am using below format to response for the webservices.

```
<Name>abc</Name>
<Detail>
 <RESPONSE>
    <Age>20</Age>
    <Address>blahblah</Address>
    <Mobile>12345</Mobile>
 </RESPONSE>
</Detail>
```

Due to the requirements, I need to return xml format data insides the `<Detail></Detail>` tag.
In my java class, I parse using Xstream and format into xml and put insides the Detail tag.

But when I test using SOAPUI , I am getting extra `<![CDATA[<RESPONSE>.. <</RESPONSE>]]>` insdies Detail tag.

How can I avoid having those CDATA tag for the xml response?

Comment: it will automatically removed when you will convert into object.

Comment: If you try to wedge XML *as text* into the content of an XML element it's going to wrap it as CDATA because it thinks you're trying to have a text element with illegal text element chars.

Comment: so when the request side parse those info, will it be ok? should I take care of removing those tags or any better way to send XML as text ? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<![CDATAP[......]]>`  is used to tell that the `XML meaning` of it should not be taken and to treat it as normal text that is called `character data`. so Parser won't seek for any XML meaning in it.
As Dave Newton and kshitij told it will automatically removed while converting it into object.
If you are not supposed to parse it as it is no issue to bother about it.

Comment: I accepted it as an answer cause I don't need to bother about like the answer is provided. For other who might confused like me first using webservices, instead of parsing the information into XML , I just used to create bean class and Web service will automatically take care of representing in XML which fulfill my needs.